# UILabels doesn't appear, even though all lines are blue

Tags: ios, xcode

My Lable object does not appear on the simulator screen. I should have an orange line or yellow circle in View controller menu, but I have none of those, looks like it should be fine.

[image]

Comment: did u set the constraint for the label?

Comment: sorry, that was a really dumb question I forgot to Trail Space to the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regarding the Blue Lines:

Those are merely "smart guides" to help you place your objects in Interface Builder with sensible margins.

#### Regarding the Label Not Being Displayed on the Simulator:

While the view controller is represented in the storyboard editor at a "generic" size of 600 x 600 points, when run on an iPhone Simulator it will likely be thinner (e.g., 320 points wide for iPhone 4(s)-5(s)). Most likely, your right-aligned label is off-screen.

#### The Solution:

Add an auto-layout constraint from the label to the container view: Control-drag from the label to the view controller background, and choose "Trailing space to container" in the black popup dialog that appears.

[Here is a tutorial on auto-layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) from a reputable source (Ray Wenderlich website).